# Autocomplete field to big a dataset

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a auto complete function which works fine on small datasets but one company has 40 thousand stock items.

```
[HttpGet]
// GET: StockInformation/Details/5
public ActionResult GetStockInfoAutoComplete()
{
        List<StockAutoCompleteInfo> info = database.GetStockAutoCompleteInfo();
        return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I no the issue is going be the amount of data so I am wondering what my best course of action is to reduce the data set is.

Should I say that for larger data set customers its should be a partial load instead of all the stock in a list first.

I have already tried the suggestions here by adding the following but that still does not appear to be enough fo the dataset.

```
<system.web.extensions>
 <scripting>
   <webServices>
       <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>

   </webServices>
 </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

The main Question is Does the above way I am encoding the data honour the maxjsonlegnth attribute or must I declare it in m controller if not I am open to suggestions on filtering.

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: Generally,  when I've been faced with something like this, I change the auto complete behavior so that the user must enter 3 or 4 characters (or whatever makes sense in context) before auto complete kicks in. Downloading 10,000 items as soon as a user types a character makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Flydog57 that's the approach I am going have to take.